# Add more props to JSX.Element in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using TypeScript with React and I want to pass a userId prop to every component rendered.
I don't want to add `userId` to props for every single component and can't figure out how to make every React component have the prop.

To make it all even harder, right now it's giving me a TS error `JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

How would I make this all work?

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;

  // I have tried many different things, but nothing worked...
  // React.ComponentType<{ user: PartialUser }>;
  
};

type PartialUser = {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }: Props) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useMeQuery();

  let me;
  let user;
  if (data?.me) {
    me = data!.me!;

    user = {
      id: me.id,
      username: me.username,
      email: me.email,
    };
  }

  if (error) console.error(error);
  const Component = children;
  return (
    <>
      {!loading && user ? (
        <Route {...rest}>
          <Component user={user} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You may be interested in [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the other way you can do is using Context API. Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context for more understanding

What I would do is I would create a custom type that would contain the user id and then use this type to create react context.

Now next step would be use this context and create a provider and then render necessary components inside this context provider. You can then consume this context in any of the child component that is at any deep level nested in this custom created context and you can get the user id.

For eg.

Create custom context type and react context:

```
export type MyContextType = {
    userId: number
}

export const MyContext = React.createContext<MyContextType>(undefined!);
```

Now use provider and pass the initial value in your main/root file

```
const context: MyContextType = {
     userId: 1 (I am assuming you would get this from API response or local storage)
};
<MyContext.Provider value={context}>
    ...nested components
    <MyComponent />
</MyContext.Provider>
```

and then in any of your nested component you can get this context and the value using:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, State> {
    static contextType = MyContext;
    context!: React.ContextType<typeof MyContext>;

    render() {
       console.log(this.context.userId); // You should be able to see 1 being printed in the console.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Component vs. Element

There is a difference between passing the component itself as the `children` prop:

```
<PrivateRoute>
  {MyComponent}
</PrivateRoute>
```

and passing an instance of the component:

```
<PrivateRoute>
  <MyComponent/>
</PrivateRoute>
```

The type `children: JSX.Element` applies to the second case and that is why you get the error:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

When you have already called the component through JSX like `<MyComponent/>` then you just get a `JSX.Element` which is not callable.

---

#### Typing the Component

You want to be passing a callable component.  If this is `react-router-dom` I would recommend using the `component` prop instead of the `children` prop since they [behave differently](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func).

We want to say that our `component` can take the standard `RouteComponentProps` and also a `user` prop.

The `PrivateRoute` itself should take all of the `RouteProps` like `to`, `exact`, etc.  But we will require a `component` prop with our modified type.

In order to call the `component` with our extra prop, we could use an inline [`render`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) function `render={props => <Component {...props} user={user} />}`.  We need to destructure it with an uppercase name in order to call it.  We could also move the authentication logic into a higher-order component and use `component={withUser(component)}`.

---

#### Other Issues

We are going to be including this `PrivateRoute` alongside other `Route` components.  So we want to render the `Redirect` only when we are actually on this `Route`.  In other words, it should be a replacement of the `component` rather than a replacement of the `Route`.  Otherwise traffic to other non-private routes will get inadvertently redirected.

You probably don't want to `Redirect` to the login page until after `loading` has finished.  You can render a loading spinner or nothing while waiting for completion.

I'm not sure why there is so much checking and assertion on `user`.  You should be able to do `const user = data?.me;` and get either a `PartialUser` or `undefined`.

---

#### Code

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

type PartialUser = {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    email: string;
};

declare function useMeQuery(): { error: any; loading: boolean; data?: { me: PartialUser } }

type ComponentProps = RouteComponentProps & {
    user: PartialUser;
}

type Props = RouteProps & {
    component: React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>;
    // disallow other methods of setting the render component
    render?: never;
    children?: never;
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: Props) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useMeQuery();

  const user = data?.me;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (user) {
          return <Component {...props} user={user} />;
        } else if (loading) {
          return null; // don't redirect until complete
        } else {
          return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

const MustHaveUser = ({user}: {user: PartialUser}) => {
    return <div>Username is {user.username}</div>
}

export const Test = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <div>Home</div>} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={MustHaveUser} />
    </Switch>
)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NVnlGN)

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it like this:

`types.ts`

```js
export interface Propys{
  userId:string;
}
```

`MyComponent.tsx`

```
import { Propys } from "./types";

const MyComponent:React.FC<Propys> = ({userId}) => {
  return <>userId</>;
}
```

Comment: Of course that's a way to do it, but it's the exact thing I didn't want to do. This means I would have to add these props to every single component I create and want to use the userId.